# Разделение строки по символам в Python

Tags: python

Есть переменная `s = "Hello World"`. Tребуется разделить ее на символы с сохранением пробелов и занести это все в список, т. е. имея строку нужно получить на выходе список, где каждый следующий элемент - это следующий символ строки(включая пробелы). Конечно, можно пробежаться циклом, типа

```
a = list()
for i in range(len("Hello World")):
    a.append("Hello World"[i])
```

Но, может, есть какой-то более оптимальный способ, который применяют в серьезных прогах(Кроме списочных выражений)?

Comment: В каком смысле разделить на символы? Строка в питоне уже и так как массив символов. `s = "hello" print(s[0])` выведет `h`

Comment: Может так: `list (s)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно исползовать генераторы списков

```
i = [c for c in "Hello world"]

print(i)
```

Answer (score 6):

Все намного проще:

```
a = list("Hello World")
```

`list` принимает на вход любой итерируемый объект (строку в данном случае), и превращает его в список из тех же элементов, из которых состоял исходный объект (в данном случае - список символов).